# HTTP Request timeout on random pages

Tags: networking, firefox, chromium

Please redirect me to the correct forum if needed.

HTTP POST requests are getting timed out. GET requests are working fine.

The problem is specific to few sites eg Quora, Lumosity, Paytm, *AskUbuntu*

To make things worse, only few pages on these sites have problems. Login page on lumosity, upvote button on quora, checkout button on paytm, post question on askubuntu etc.

I tried with Firefox, Opera, Chromium, Arora, Midori, Epiphany, cURL, wget

They are *working as expected* with Midori, cURL, wget but not other browsers

I even tried Ubuntu 14.10 and Ubuntu 15.04 (Things are working fine on Windows) I have re-formatted my entire system. So every thing is configured with default values

I am not able to find any common denominator. Please help

Comment: I dont have either of these networks

Comment: try using a vpn. about a week ago, askubuntu wouldn't load for me because it would hang on what ever image service askubuntu uses. I fired up an encrypted vpn and sure enough, even after routing my address half way around the globe, askubuntu loaded in less than 3 seconds. I firmly contacted my ISP about this issue and they were clueless but magically, by the time I got off the phone with them, things were working as expected.

Comment: Tried that. No luck.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is this on eithernet or wifi? Linux tends to be worse on the wifi side than Windows.

Comment: @saiarcot895 both :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some debugging with Wireshark, I finally resolved my problem by decreasing [mtu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)

The command is `sudo ifconfig eth0 mtu 576`

Comment: Could you please help me understand what's going on? My OSX sends 1500 byte packet and works. My ubuntu VM in default was set to 1500 but it wouldn't work. I changed it to 576 from 1500 as you've suggested and the ubuntu VM started working.

Comment: I have the same question